# Can't find dependency for org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1

Tags: neo4j, maven-3, spring-data-neo4j

I was trying to get the dependencies from the repository, given below the pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion> 4.0.0 </modelVersion>
    <groupId> com.tp.neo4j </groupId>
    <artifactId> springdata-neo4j </artifactId>
    <version> 1.0 </version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.springframework.data </groupId>
            <artifactId> spring-data-neo4j </artifactId>
            <version> 3.1.2.RELEASE </version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

All dependencies except `org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1` got downloaded.  And showing the below error.

```
[INFO] Building springdata-neo4j 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.409s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 28 13:07:07 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]Failed to execute goal on project springdata-neo4j: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tp.neo4j:springdata-neo4j:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1 in https://maven......../repositories/core-releases was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of core-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I tried excluding the same. But still not working.

```
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

I removed the `\.m2\repository\org\neo4j` folder and tried again. Still not working. I noticed that the neo4j-cypher-dsl have a version 2.0.1 but almost all others have 2.2.5. I wonder, why only one dependency is missing in core-releases.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using such an old version? That's almost like 2 years outdated?

You will have to add `m2.neo4j.org` as maven repository to your repositories section.

Comment: It is working for `<artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>   <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>`. But now  showing compilation error on  `org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository`. `The import org.springframework cannot be resolved`.

Comment: Added `<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-releases</id>
   <name>Spring Releases</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>neo4j</id>
   <name>Neo4j</name>
   <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>` . Still same error.

Comment: can you post the exception when upgrading version? you should consider using this version and focus on this so as to find what's wrong and not use such an old version as Michael stated.

Comment: @NaaN `m2.neo4j.org` is not the actual repository, but just the landing page. You can find a list of repositories in the repositories tab. You can use e.g. `https://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases`